# Como consertar background image que não funciona?

Tags: html, css

adicionei um background image em um site for fun apenas para estudo e ele não aparece quando abro o projeto. Já me certifiquei de linkar o código a pasta style certa e também na tag background-image fazer a ligação das pastas certas e mesmo assim nenhuma pasta aparece. alguém sabe porque esse erro persiste ? já procurei em vários lugares em não achei nenhuma solução! seria um erro do meu sublime ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>ｓｏ　ｓｃａｎｄａｌｏｕｓ</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/stylef1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="main">
            <div class="center">
                
            </div><!-- center-->
        </section> <!-- main-->

        
        <script src="Java/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

section.main
{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../Imagens/image1.jpg"); 
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image: site sem imagem como background]

Answer (score -3):

Você teria que definir um tamanho para o seu section ou se você quiser colocar ela como fundo de pagina ficaria assim:

```
body {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-image: url("./imagens/imagem.jpg"); 
}
```

Comment: não funcionou nao

Answer (score -3):

Boas, verifica se este código irá funcionar.

Porque o código que colocaste, ele está um pouco incorreto, porque? Adicionaste um ponto a mais no URL do CSS, verifica novamente com este novo código.

```
section.main
{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../Imagens/image1.jpg"); 
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```